# Getting lastIndexOf on a Dropdown

Tags: javascript

Here's my attempt to get the last item in the dropdown and check it:

```
if (day.lastIndexOf(day.length) == 28) {

..do something

}
```

day var is set to reference dropdown control.  Obviously I am not doing this right.  How do I know where I can apply lastIndexOf on a dropdownlist?  How do I get at it's array?  I tried this also but it doesn't work, syntax error:

```
day.options.lastIndexOf(day.length)
```

one would think that should work, options is an array of values I think..has to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

coffeeaddict,

The lastIndexOf() method returns the position of the last occurrence of a specified string value, searching backwards from the specified position in a string.

You're probably trying to do this:

```
if (day.options[day.options.length-1].value == 28) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
day.options[day.options.length-1]
```

Comment: If so, `day.options[day.options.length-1].value` should work fine.

Comment: @Roatin: Let it go. The `value` part was important and your solution didn't have it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var o = day.options;
var option = o[o.length - 1];
```

Note that `option` is an Option object with `text` and `value` properties that you can use for your checks.